# Audit on oracle schema for dml statements

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, audit

I need to secure an oracle user for doing inserts/updates/deletes from outside programs written by me.

I googled a bit around to find what I need. I know you can use own written db triggers.
And I now there are two major systems from oracle (at least that is what I found).
You can use fine grained auditing. And you can use the audit trail.

I think in my case the audit trail comes close but just isn't what I am looking for. Because I need to now from which program the connection to the DB is coming. For example I need to register all connections that are doing inserts/updates/deletes with there statements executed that are coming from sql developer or toad. But all the other connections may pass without audit.

On daily basis I have lots of connections so registering everything is too much overload.

I hope one of you have a good idea on how to set this up.

Regards

Comment: Your title and tags talk about auditing changes.  But then your description talks about "securing" and seems to imply that you want to prevent DML unless it is coming from an application.  Is the goal to allow the DML and only audit DML that is coming from something other than an application?  Or is the goal to prevent that DML from running?  How secure does the solution need to be?  Since the application name has to come from the application which is running on the client machine, a competent user could easily hack that data by manipulating their machine.

Comment: It doesn't have to be secure. Users may do some inserts/updates and deletes but we just need to keep track of them. We had in the past some things have gone wrong by someone doing an update and forgot something in his where clause. If we can keep track of these changes we can see which records might have been infected. So it is pure auditing and no security that is why I mentioned only the audit tag

Comment: OK.  Is the goal to know what SQL statement was run?  Or what rows were updated?  Assuming rows are getting modified by other processes and that some time elapses between the user action and the problem being discovered, knowing the SQL statement may not tell you which rows met the statement's criteria at the time it was executed.  What is the lag between a user making a mistake and the problem being identified?  Could you possibly use flashback technology rather than auditing?

Comment: The goal is to now which user did the action and what the sql statement was. We don't need the rows affected. We can distract that afterwards from the sql. It isn't so that every day something bad happens (at least I don't hope so :-) ). We could use flashback to get the right data back if it didn't happen to long ago. But I only need the changes made by users directly in de db and not by all the programs we use, because they work fine and don't make mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a product of Oracle: Oracle Audit Vault and Database Firewall. Because you want to know also from which program the connection comes, you need the Database Firewall. It can monitor all traffic through the database, specifying the IP address and the client from which the connection was started. You can also specify if you want to audit DML or DDL,or other statements. Data is stored locally in the product's database,not in the secure target (your database). Just have a look, it it just what you need: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/audit-vault-and-database-firewall/overview/overview-1877404.html